# How to make C++ compiler exploit trivial data types?

Tags: c++, optimization

Suppose I want to wrap some primitive data types while letting the compiler exploit the nature of the »primitive« data. Without a constructor, the `wrapped` items are simply initialised and copied using `memset()`/`memcpy()` as expected (clang 8.0.0, gcc 8.3 on x86-64).

```
struct wrapped
{
    constexpr wrapped() noexcept: n{0} {}
    unsigned int n;
};

wrapped *clone(wrapped const *const ptr, std::size_t const sz)
{
    wrapped *const result{new wrapped[sz]{}};
    std::copy_n(ptr, sz, result);
    return result;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/X4i8RP

As soon as I supply a constructor (either as shown above or by providing an in-class initialisation for `n`), the code generated by the compiler »explodes« into a whopping 111 lines (clang 8.0.0), consisting of an unrolled copying loop instead of a simple call to `memcpy()`. The result in gcc 8.3 isn't quite as long, but also doesn't take advantage of `memcpy()` anymore.

Is there anything I can do to make the compiler realise that the type continues to be »trivially copyable«? I've played around with `constexpr` and `noexcept` rule-of-threes and -fives without success.

Note that this behaviour is *not* (solely) related to `wrapped` being POD since defining a destructor also means the type isn't POD, but doesn't cause this compiler behaviour.

Comment: You don't give the compiler options. In a fully optimised build you may see more similarity to the naïve example you are comparing.

Comment: Second  point: In an optimised build you are generally optimising for speed. The unrolled loop may be faster than calling memcpy. If space is a problem you may want to specify `-Os`

Comment: Specifying `-Os` reduces it to 39 bytes for clang and 37 for gcc.

Comment: That doesn't mean it'll be faster - that depends on how often it is run. Of course without a constructor that's only 25 or 26 bytes. But the difference here is that you are initialising the memory.

Comment: @Ben you're right, with `-Os` clang chooses essentially the same loop as gcc. I realise loop unrolling generally improves performance, but I'm also concerned about locality and cache effects. In the case from which I developed the example there was extreme bloat due to unrolled loops being inlined all over the place, which made me wonder why it even made a difference…

Comment: I agree with your concerns, I generally prefer smaller code because of cache effects. However in this case the loop unroll avoids a call to memset which would itself use the cache. Performance is going to depend on whether memset is already cached or the program would benefit later from memset being cached.

Comment: Or in other words, profile.

Comment: @Ben I've added initialisation on both sides to make a »fairer« comparison.

Comment: The link doesn't have initialisation on the left??? By which I mean the member `n` is still not initialised.

Comment: @Ben on the left, `wrapped` is POD, so `new wrapped[sz]{}` value-initialises, which zero-initialises

Comment: Unrelated, but your choice of emphasis and words to emphasize makes your sentences harder to read with no apparent reason.